# Show that the following inequallity holds

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $I=[a,b] $ and let $f,g,h \in C(I) $ such that $h(t)>0 $ for any $t\in I$.
> Assume in addition that $$ f\left(t\right)\leq g\left(t\right)+\intop_{a}^{t}f\left(x\right)h\left(x\right)dx $$
> Prove that for any $t\in I $ the following inequality holds:
> $$ f\left(t\right)\leq g\left(t\right)+\intop_{a}^{t}h\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)e^{\underset{x}{\overset{t}{\intop}}h\left(y\right)dy}dx $$

**My work so far:**

I followed a hint and defined $$ F\left(t\right)=\intop_{a}^{t}f\left(x\right)h\left(x\right)dx $$

and then I showed that $$ F'\left(t\right)-h\left(t\right)F\left(t\right)\leq h\left(t\right)g\left(t\right)  $$

Now, my idea is to solve the equation

$ F'\left(t\right)-h\left(t\right)F\left(t\right)=h\left(t\right)g\left(t\right) $

a solution would be of the form:

$$ F\left(t\right)=\intop_{a}^{t}h\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)e^{-\intop_{a}^{x}h\left(y\right)dy}dxe^{\intop_{a}^{t}h\left(y\right)dy} $$

But I'm not sure if it really helps or how to proceed.

Any idea would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried iterating the integral, as in one of the possible proofs of the Gronwall lemma ( see for example lemma 8.4 on page 213 in the book of LeGall: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-31089-3 )